# Converter control simulation on simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, control-theory

I am struggling with a little project I decided to tackle. I am trying to replicate an example I found on a book using matlab simulink but I have no experience with simulink and control theory (I do understand the principles etc.).

The control block diagram is given but I do not understand some blocks and how to add my input (sine wave block on simulink)?

Here are the details:

[Example I wish to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BetVY.png)

[Schematic of the converter and desired control block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ss39.png)

If anyone could give me a little insight or direct me to some examples from which I could build on an understanding would be great!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The portion entitled controller is the closed-loop feedback control for the system.  K(s) would typically contain some type of PI control.  In a more complicated control system, the structure of K(s) may be a little different, but will usually always contain an integration in order to ensure that the system eventually settles at the desired value.

The input Iref is your current command.  In this case you would inject your sinusoid here which would produce a current waveform matching your desired output.  If your desired output.

Output m is the modulating waveform produced by the controller.  Everything inside the half-bridge converter section is a representation of the converter and everything that it is interfaced to (voltage sources).

The feedforward filter here is also a very important component.  Since Vs contains an alternating waveform, the feed forward filter allows the system to respond to changes in Vs without relying on feedback compensation K(s).  This helps to decouple current regulation from changes in voltage VD.

To start with the project, you can probably build the half bridge converter as shown.  You can inject 400*cos(377t - pi/2) as VD.

For the feedback compensator K(s) you can feed the input into two gains (Ki and Kp) which you will select values for later.  At the output of Ki insert an integrator (1/s) then sum the output of Kp and the integrator together.

For the feed-forward filter, you should probably just use a low pass filter with a gain of 1 at DC.  The low pass filter prevents noise from entering the system.  In this case you are running a simulation, so there will be no noise.  However, the filter will eliminate any algebraic loops, which can cause warnings or errors in the simulation.

You can input your control signal at Iref.